# Input Field Is Longer Than Its Containing Table Cell (HTML)

Tags: html

Trying to format a field using HTML.
I have the following:

```
<table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 65px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblKeywords" runat="server" Text="Keywords"
                 AssociatedControlID="txtKeywords" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtKeywords" Width="100%" runat="server"
                 MaxLength="256" placeholder="Use comma to seperate keywords." />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Checking the result, the textbox `txtKeywords` is 4 pixels longer than its cell.

I assume those are the 4 pixels of the border; what is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: That is not html. It's got some asp.net controls. Can you show us the result html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following CSS rule to change box-sizing to "border-box":

```
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

IMHO this results in behavior that is far easier to grok. For example, a width of "100%" then means 100% including border, margin and padding. You can read more about it here: http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Also, as a side note, consider not using tables to align your form fields. Have a look at my blog post about it: http://davidtanzer.net/css_vertical_align

Comment: I wouldn't advise to set that on a universal selector. That will most probably screw up his whole layout.

Comment: @Roman You are right, if there already is a lot of CSS code, this is probably a bad idea. OTOH, I start all of my style sheets with this rule, and I think it makes my life easier...

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

The simplest way would be to set the input to use `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
input.myClass {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

this works in *most* browsers.